# CAboutDlg aboutDlg and local variable

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a question seems simple but confuse me. I didn't get answer from Google. In Visual Studio MFC project, I test this sample code:

```
    void CEmptySingleDocApp::OnAppAbout()
    {
        TmpVarAboutDlg();
    }

    void TmpVarAboutDlg() {
        CAboutDlg aboutDlg;
        aboutDlg.DoModal();
    }
```

The aboutDlg in the sample code is a local variable, but why the code runs well? My blind guess is that when create a CAboutDlg, you are using a resource, which is in this line:

```
    CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() noexcept : CDialogEx(IDD_ABOUTBOX)
```

Do I guess right?

Comment: `why the code runs well?` Because `DoModal()` runs a "*modal loop*" which does not return until the user closes the about dialog. Therefore the entire lifetime of the dialog is spent inside the `TmpVarAboutDlg` function call, and so a local variable is enough for that.

Comment: `you are using a resource` That's correct, but unrelated to `aboutDlg` being a local variable.

Comment: Great thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

`aboutDlg` is indeed a local variable that is destroyed when it goes out of scope at the end of `TmpVarAboutDlg`. This is not a problem as the code calls [DoModal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class#domodal). `DoModal` only returns after the dialog has been dismissed, and its corresponding C++ object is no longer needed.

While the code does use an application-provided resource to construct the dialog, the same principles hold if the dialog were created from an in-memory dialog template, or dynamically through code.

Note that while a program is blocked on a modal dialog, the system still dispatches messages for other windows. For example, if you move the dialog, the system will generate `WM_PAINT` messages for windows underneath it as appropriate.